# Request method 'POST' not supported in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a project in Spring Boot Billing. I have successfully build and run this project but there is some issue.

When i am trying insert data via POST method but Browser shows POST method not supported.

Here is my controller
      BillingController.java

```
 package com.billing.controller;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.billing.model.Restaurant_billing;
import com.billing.model.Restaurant_billingDao;
import com.billing.model.billing;
import com.billing.model.billingDao;
import com.billing.model.itemDao;
import com.billing.model.tax_billing;
import com.billing.model.tax_billingDao;


@Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restaurant")
public class BillingController {

@Autowired
private itemDao itemDao;

@Autowired
private billingDao billingDao;

@Autowired
private Restaurant_billingDao restaurant_billingDao;

@Autowired
private tax_billingDao tax_billingDao;

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session sesion=null;
org.hibernate.Transaction tx=null;

   @RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =   
   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
    @ResponseBody 
 public String R_billing(@RequestBody final Restaurant_billing r_billing[] ,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request)
 throws ServletException { 

  try{

      billing billingObject = new billing();
      billingDao.save(billingObject);
      int billing_id = billingObject.getId();

      tax_billing tax_billing= new tax_billing();

      tax_billing.setBilling_id(billing_id);
      tax_billing.setTax_amount("140");
      tax_billingDao.save(tax_billing);      


    for(Restaurant_billing prof:r_billing){

    prof.setBilling_id(billing_id); 
    restaurant_billingDao.save(prof);

   }
     }
    catch(Exception ex){
    return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
       }
    return ("User profession added successfully");  
     }


   }
```

Here is my model class

```
Restaurant_billing.java

package com.billing.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name ="billing_restaurant")
public class Restaurant_billing {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id; 

@Column(name="billing_id")
private int billing_id;

@Column(name="itemid")
private String itmeid;

@Column(name="quantity")
private String quantity;

@Column(name="billing_type")
private String billing_type;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getBilling_id() {
    return billing_id;
}

public void setBilling_id(int billing_id) {
    this.billing_id = billing_id;
}

public String getItmeid() {
    return itmeid;
}

public void setItmeid(String itmeid) {
    this.itmeid = itmeid;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getBilling_type() {
    return billing_type;
}

public void setBilling_type(String billing_type) {
    this.billing_type = billing_type;
}



}
```

Comment: How is your browser calling `/create`? It's annotated as requiring JSON. Perhaps the content type of the request you are sending is something else?

Comment: Side note: why do you have both `@Controller` and `@RestController` annotations on your controller class? Using `@RestController` already marks the class as controller so there is no need for the `@Controller` annotation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use @Controller use only @RestController and also assign sesion and tx values.
After that you just try the following code,

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public @RequestBody Restaurant_billing R_billing(final HttpServletResponse response){ 

  try{

      billing billingObject = new billing();

     //Here set the billingObject values

      billingDao.save(billingObject);

      int billing_id = billingObject.getId();

      tax_billing tax_billing= new tax_billing();

      tax_billing.setBilling_id(billing_id);
      tax_billing.setTax_amount("140");
      tax_billingDao.save(tax_billing);      


    for(Restaurant_billing prof:r_billing){

    prof.setBilling_id(billing_id); 
    restaurant_billingDao.save(prof);

   }
     }
    catch(Exception ex){
    return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
       }
    return ("User profession added successfully");  
     }
//here return obj

   }
```